# Can I set the proxy on the command line when using org.apache.commons.httpclient?

Tags: java, http, proxy, apache-commons

If an application uses the java.net.* routines, I can set a proxy when invoking the application like this:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000 <whatever-the-app-is>
```

However, I have an application (which I can't change) using org.apache.commons.httpclient to do the http communication. It doesn't specify a procxy server, but it does use the default HttpConnection. Is there some way I can tell the apache http client from the command line to use a proxy server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can. The only way is for the application to read the System property and then set it in the [DefaultHttpParams](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/DefaultHttpParams.html) object.

Take a look at [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg02586.html) on the httpclient-user group for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That's not the only way (you can set proxies other ways but all of them involve changing the app, as far as I can see)

Answer (score 6):

When using the HTTPClient builder use the useSystemProperties() method to enable the standard JVM -D proxy parameters.
See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#useSystemProperties()

Example:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .useSystemProperties()
    .build();
```

Now use -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 to configure the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But here is a code I found this code in an old project, which should've worked:

```
try {
   String proxyHost = System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
   int proxyPort = 0;
   try {
        proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("https.proxyPort"));
   } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("No proxy port found");
   }

   System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

   ProxySelector ps = ProxySelector.getDefault();
   List<Proxy> proxyList = ps.select(new URI(targetUrl));
   Proxy proxy = proxyList.get(0);
   if (proxy != null) {
         InetSocketAddress addr = ((InetSocketAddress) proxy.address());
         if (addr != null) {
             proxyHost = addr.getHostName();
             proxyPort = addr.getPort();
         }
   }

   boolean useProxy = proxyHost != null && proxyHost.length() > 0;

   if (useProxy) {
         httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
   }

} catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't (easily)change the app, but maybe I'll need to do that after all